# How to bind to a property in a different object for a computed property

Tags: ember.js

I would like to bind to a property of an ArrayProxy for a computed property of an Object that is a member of that Array. I have set up a JS fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/sohara/MZeUu/31/

As you can see in the code below, my computed property depends on an aggregate computed property in the thingsController. However, if you click the delete button the percentWeight computer property is not called again because I don't know how to get this function to bind to the totalWeight computed property in the thingsController. I'm sure there's a way to do this..... any ideas?

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Thing = Ember.Object.extend({
    weight: null,

    percentWeight: function() {
        return (this.get('weight') / App.thingsController.get('totalWeight')) * 100;
    }.property('weight')
    // This below doesn't work - can't access this property error
    //}.property('weight', 'App.thingsController.totalWeight')
});

App.thingsController = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
    content: [
        App.Thing.create({weight: 100}),
        App.Thing.create({weight: 200}),
        App.Thing.create({weight: 300}),
        App.Thing.create({weight: 400})
        ],

    totalWeight: function() {
        var totalWeight = 0;
        this.get('content').forEach(function(item) {
            totalWeight += item.get('weight');
        });
        return totalWeight;
    }.property('@each.weight'),

    destroy: function(item) {
        this.removeObject(item);
    }

});

App.ThingView = Ember.View.extend({
    deleteButton: Ember.Button.extend({
        click: function(event) {
            var item = this.get('content');
            App.thingsController.destroy(item);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: I got some very generous help from @wycats on irc and ended up with this jsfiddle that solves my problem and also corrects some violation of mvc that was in my code: http://jsfiddle.net/MZeUu/34/

Answer (score 1):

Your missing one binding => totalWeightBinding and some restructuring of the code so that App.Thing is aware of the App.thingsController.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
App.thingsController = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
    totalWeight: function() {
        var totalWeight = 0;
        this.get('content').forEach(function(item) {
            totalWeight += item.get('weight');
        });
        return totalWeight;
    }.property('@each.weight'),

    destroy: function(item) {
        this.removeObject(item);
    }
});

App.Thing = Ember.Object.extend({
    weight: null,
    totalWeightBinding: 'App.thingsController.totalWeight',
    percentWeight: function() {
        return (this.get('weight') / this.get('totalWeight')) * 100;
    }.property('weight')
});
var things = [
  App.Thing.create({weight: 100}),
  App.Thing.create({weight: 200}),
  App.Thing.create({weight: 300}),
  App.Thing.create({weight: 400})
]
App.thingsController.set('content', things);

</script>
```